# Efficient [JS?] algorithm to list and update multiple location buy/sell prices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

No, this is not for an interview question, or for cryptos! :)
It is for a personal not-for-profit web app to supplement a game.

This question is part finance, part code.
I am writing this web app in Vue, so I prefer a JavaScript solution, but an abstract approach is fine, pseudo-code would be great, and I should be able to translate any impl in to JavaScript.

The scenario is this:
Multiple locations (ex: "stores") buy and sell multiple items for different prices.
The prices change randomly (supposedly due to supply/demand, but this is irrelevant).
There will be 100-1000ish locations, and 10-100ish items.
Most locations (estimated 80-90%) will only buy/sell a few items.
Some locations (estimated 1-10%) will buy/sell many or all items.
Some locations (estimated 50%) may only buy and not sell, or only sell and not buy.

I want to show an exhaustive list of all locations that have an item buy price to all locations that have a sell price for that item (akin to permutations/combinations, but with many expected gaps).
The final rendered data must be just a simple list/array of objects (keyed/valued).

A paginated list of 99M objects (1000 stores * (1000  - 1) stores * 100 items) would be a worst case, but it is expected for there to be **many many** gaps in the data, so hopefully there are **way less** than 1M objects (I am hoping for no more than 100,000; these don't have to all be live in memory; I could opt to load them from storage).

Example (sorted by Item and Buy Location to better see the example data set):

`Item     Buy Location   Buy Price Ratio Sell Price   Sell Location
Item A   Location A     4         0.5   2            Location B
Item A   Location A     4         2.0   8            Location C
Item A   Location B     6         0.66  4            Location A
Item A   Location B     6         1.33  8            Location C
Item A   Location C     10        0.4   4            Location A
Item A   Location C     10        0.2   2            Location B
Item B   Location A     3         0.33  1            Location B
Item B   Location A     3         1.33  4            Location C
Item B   Location B     3         0.66  2            Location A
Item B   Location B     3         1.33  4            Location C
Item B   Location C     5         0.4   2            Location A
Item B   Location C     5         0.2   1            Location B`

Each column in the list is sortable; the default sort will be "Ratio", which will show the best combinations of places to buy from and sell to.
When any price is updated Vue will automatically update the list and re-sort it.

Now, I have my ideas on how to do this, but it is horribly inefficient because my solution is to re-generate the entire list whenever any single price changes.
Since the final output needs to be a list that can be arbitrarily sorted, there is no real way to index or direct access the items.
If the price for Location C's Item A Buy Price changes, there is no way to say "update row X column Y", or even just "update row X".

But, I suspect that I am missing something.
I imagine that this is a fairly common task that has been implemented before in ways that scale.
Example: A "simple" buy/sell price chart across multiple exchanges.
I have thought about looking at open Crypto[Bot] code, but this seems more like a "Finance" question that I am looking to understand than a coding question that I am looking to copy.

How would you implement this?
What sort of dataset(s) would you use?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems off topic to me as it's very broad, it's not a specific programming issue. It would be much easier to answer if the list was either all the items at one location, or all the locations for one item, or the highest or lowest *n* ratios. Otherwise you will end up with your n*(n-1)*y list of ratios.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion

- The 1M lines of data is too much for user to read in once.
- The 1M array size is not much big for javascript (~10MB you can inspect in your application [see how](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101)) but render all of it to DOM element can be a very big problem.

> How would you implement this?

So in this case I will go with pagination or aggregation (e.g. first 10 highest ratio for each item).

Example:

```
computed: {
  displayItems () {
    // This will update when one of rawItems, currentPage, pageSize updated
    return doFilterOrSort(rawItems).slice(currentPage * pageSize, pageSize)
  }
}
```

This will solve the problem of too many DOM elements (As above I assume update 1M array size is fast enough to not be a bottleneck).

In case of your data is changing very frequently like 10 times in a second. You can improve this by throttling or debouncing to reduce times to render.

Example of throttling:

```
watch: {
  rawItems () {
    if (!ticking) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        displayItems = doFilterOrSort(rawItems).slice(currentPage * pageSize, pageSize)
        ticking = false
      })
      ticking = true
    }
  }
}
```

In case of you want to have behavior like infinite scrolling you can do it by recycle DOM elements that already out of screen. See example in [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List).

> What sort of dataset(s) would you use?

You didn't tell which format of data you retrieved (in initial and each update; by store? by item?) so it hard to answer.

I assume the number of stores and items are fixed (not frequently update) and each update is for an item from a store. Denote *n* and *m* for the number of store and item.

I will use 3 arrays:

First array for keep buy/sell value for each item in each store. You can update this easily in *O(1)*.

Second array for keep object of ratio for each combination of store of each item like:

```
[
  [aa, ab, ac],
  [ba, bb, bc],
  [ca, cb, cc]
]

// 3 stores, 1 item, each element is { r, a, b }
// r for ratio, a buy store, b sell store
```

You can update this with *O(n⋅n)* e.g. update a: loop through 1 to n, for i = 2 update *ab* and *ba*.

Third array for keep the same object from previous plus flattering or grouping. Do sort or grouping this will cost *O((n⋅n⋅m) log (n⋅n⋅m))* (yes this is a bottleneck you need to pay attention on this and method is depend on your array shape).

In bigger scale (or all above doesn't help, sorry for that) I think instead of send all data to client you should aggregate it in the server then send it through the web socket.

Comment: Thanks! I will tweak my codepen based on this and other feedback I have received elsewhere. Once the codepen is stable, if your answer helped I'll gladly accept it! :)